# Ireports Chave Estrangeira: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: br.com.tkcsapcd.model.bean.ProjetoInicio

Tags: java, jsp, relatório, ireport, ide

estou com um erro na hora de compilar o relatório no Irepor, na primeira vez, que compilei deu certo, porem, quando fechei o Ireports 3.7.3, e abri novamente tentei compilar surge, o erro abaixo:

Compiling to file... C:\Users\Josue\Desktop\Relatorio_Ireport\termoabertura.jasper
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRValidationException: Report design not valid :       1. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: br.com.tkcsapcd.model.bean.ProjetoInicio     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.verifyDesign(JRAbstractCompiler.java:258)     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:140)     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:215)     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(JasperCompileManager.java:131)     at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.IReportCompiler.run(IReportCompiler.java:514)     at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572)     at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997)
Compilation running time: 156

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No XML do relatório configuro os atributos que serão carregados pela classe:

Trechos:

```
#<field name="termoaberturaprojeto" class="java.lang.String"/>
#<field name="versao" class="java.lang.String"/>
#<field name="autor" class="java.lang.String"/>
#<field name="aprovacao" class="java.lang.String"/>
```

Trechos:

Toda vez, que fecho o relatório e abro carrega o class:

textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String">
![CDATA[$F{projetoinicio}.getCodigoprojeto()]]>

textFieldExpression>

O certo e não carregar o class:
textFieldExpression>

textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String">

Observação adicionei o JAR do projeto! Alguém sabe como resolver? Obrigado!